# jquery validator with asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i need to understand how i can get the access to objects asp with jquery because i have a file that it's register in page load of the code behind of my aspx that have the script need to do a validation, i read in different's site that i can do it with this `<%=txtName.UniqueID %>` but doesn't work i going to put my code and anyone could help me. thanks

**the button that trigger the validation this method in the script file**

```
    <asp:Button ID="btnOk" CssClass="btnOk" runat="server" Text="Ok" />
```

**the js**

```
$(".btnOk").click(validateData);

function validateData() {

$("form").validate({
    rules: 
    {
        '<%=txtName.UniqueID %>': "required"        
    }
});
}
```

**my code behind where i registered the scripts**

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "MyScript", "<script language=javascript src='js/SetIndicators.js'> </script>");
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Validator", "<script language=javascript src='js/jquery.validate.js'> </script>");
```

**UPDATE**

this is the text input that i need to validate

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtLayerName" CssClass="txtLayerName" runat="server"> </asp:TextBox>
```

With `'<%=txtName.UniqueID %>'` and `<%=txtName.UniqueID %>` doesn't work also with `'.txtLayerName'`

**UPDATE 2**

this is the render name by asp

```
<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtLayerName" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtLayerName" class="txtLayerName required" />
```

Comment: See my Edit!  I'm sure it will work for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jquery validate using the NAME property of html inputs, not the ID.    it's been a while since i used webforms, so i don't know if the name and id match.  but it might be worth looking into.

EDIT:  i've added validation on the fly with great success like so:

```
    $(function(){
       $("form").validate(); 

       $('.txtLayerName').each(function () {

            //add the required validator to these!
            $(this).rules('add', {required: true});

        }); 
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want:

```
'<%= txtLayerName.ClientID %>': "required"
```

Also, keep in mind that you can use a CSS class instead of defining the rules like that, which is a bit easier. E.g.:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtLayerName" CssClass="txtLayerName required" runat="server" />
```

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what exactly do you mean?  Is it not validating, throwing JavaScript errors, allowing the form to submit unvalidated, etc?

Comment: is not making validations at all **notes that if i put the generated name by asp it works but that's not the idea**

Comment: What is that name that ASP.NET is rendering?

Comment: i modify the question when the render name

Answer (score 1):

I have had good luck using jQuery's ["ends with" selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) because the server side ID of the control is always the last bit of the client ID string.

for instance, your button's client ID may be something like "ctl00$foo$bar$btnOk"
then your jQuery would be:

```
$("[id$=btnOk]").click(validateData);
```

then you can do the same thing with the TextBox.

```
rules: 
{
    $("[id$=txtLayerName]").attr("id") : "required"        
}
```

UPDATE:

try this instead:

```
rules = {};
rules[$("[id$=txtLayerName]").attr("id")] = "required";
```

since objects are essentially just arrays with direct named access to the elements, you can create an array and use it like an object.

Comment: hi, and thank's for asking but the problem it's that i can't put that selector like an option in the rules of the jquery validator. but the selector works

Answer (score 0):

That does work, as I'm using it, though I would guess that `'<%=txtName.UniqueID %>'` doesn't need the `''`'s to work...

If you're using .NET 4 and have `clientIDMode = Static`, you can also use the following script and and use the names as you normally would.

```
    $("#aspForm input:not(:hidden)").each(function () {
        var i = $(this).get(0);
        i.name = i.id;
    });
```